# Unit testing Angular directive expression attribute which passes promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I've spent a bunch of time trying to unit test a directive which generates/tracks a promise within the controller, an example of how this is accomplished can be seen here: https://plnkr.co/edit/d8wMq0qlpiE4P25q5lhB

The directive:

```
.directive('testDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            save: '&',
        },
        template: '<div><a href="#" ng-click="handleSave($event)">Click Here</a></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, controllers) {

            scope.someData = {
                saving: false
            };

            scope.handleSave = function() {
                scope.someData.name = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
                scope.someData.saving = true;
                scope.someData.error = false;
                scope.someData.id = null;
                return scope.save()(scope.someData)
                    .then(function(data) {
                        scope.someData = data;
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        scope.someData.error = true;
                    })
                    .finally(function() {
                        scope.someData.saving = false;
                    });
            };

        }
    };
})
```

The controller:

```
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $q, $timeout) {
    $scope.saveCtrl = function(directiveData) {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            $timeout(function() {
                if (Math.round(Math.random())) {
                    directiveData.id = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
                    resolve(directiveData);
                } else {
                    reject(new Error());
                }
            }, 2000)
        });
    }
});
```

The template:

```
<test-directive save="saveCtrl"></test-directive>
```

It's functional as a component as seen in the example, but the test fails to complete because the .finally() never gets called. I've tried a lot of variations to force $digest, but nothing seems to complete the promise.

Comment: i'm an angular n00b, is there a way to inject a directive into a test and call the `link` method directly, or do you have to compile and digest it to get it to evaluate?

Comment: for a minimally viable test, is it possible to remove the $timeout from the `saveCtrl`, so the promise is resolved instantly? and to remove the non-determinism from the test by not using random?? Ideally there could be 2 separate tests a `reject` branch and a `resolve` branch?

Comment: @dm03514 Absolutely, I added it to the functionality on the actual directive to recreate an async call, you could totally remove the timeout and resolve/reject immediately. The only good way of calling the `link` method is through these compiled directives, but you can always split testable functionality out to a separate `controller`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I got it. https://plnkr.co/edit/CBvrZo4g9LjJC61VV0wp

```

```
$scope.saveCtrl = function(data) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (Math.round(Math.random())) {
                var id = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
                resolve(id);
            } else {
                reject(new Error());
            }
            elementScope.$apply();
            $scope.$apply();
        }, 100);
   });
};
```

```

There was an undefined var at line 39 and the angular timeout was behaving oddly. This should cause the full flow of the directives save to be tested with the timeout. I think the timeout may not be needed however as you can assume the instant timeout case without any loss of testing.

Comment: HA, I would have never guessed adding an additional digest to the mock promise, crazy!